# Optimize my read() loop C (two loops in one)

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

I need to read files and store them in mainbuff and mainbuff2.

I should use only syscalls like `open()`,`read()`,`write()`, etc.

I don't want to store them in stack,what if it will be very large? Heap alloc is better.

this code works:

```
...
    char charbuf;
    char *mainbuff1=malloc(100);
    char *mainbuff2=malloc(100);
    while (read(file1, &charbuf, 1)!=0)
            mainbuff1[len++]=charbuf;
    while (read(file2, &charbuf, 1)!=0)
            mainbuff2[len2++]=charbuf;
...
```

But mainbuff is only 100 chars. Better solution is alloc mainbuff after counting chars in file like this:

```
...
    char charbuf;
    while (read(file1, &charbuf, 1)!=0)
            len++;
    while (read(file2, &charbuf, 1)!=0)
            len2++;
    char *mainbuff1=malloc(len);
    char *mainbuff2=malloc(len2);
...
```

and then again repeat `while` loop and read bytes into mainbuff.

But 2 loops(first will read and count and second will read) will be non-efficient and slow for large files. Need to do it in one or something else more efficient. Please,help! Have no idea!

Comment: profile before optimizing!

Comment: You should take into account the result of your calls to `read`. You need to handle differently the `-1`, `0` and `1` possible results. And you could grow the buffers (by allocating a new one and copying into it the old one) while reading them. BTW, if you want to be efficient you should `read` more than one byte at once (typically read a chunk of several kilobytes at once).

Comment: Have you seen mmap(2)?

Comment: For this reason buffered readers were invented. A class reads X amount of information from the file, and allows you access to it by some of it's methods. When you read most of it off, it will fetch some more from the file. Bottom line, it's a bad idea to have the entire file in memory, you read the file chunck by chunk with the chunk size being some multiple of 4096 bytes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `fstat` to get the file size instead of reading twice.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main() {
    struct stat sbuf;
    int fd = open("filename", O_RDWR);
    fstat(fd, &sbuf);
    char *buf = malloc(sbuf.st_size + 1);
}
```

But, really, the time to worry about efficiency is after it *works* too slowly.

Comment: what if sometimes I need to read it from STDIN from terminal(fd=0)?

Comment: Require the User to provide the size.

Answer (score 5):

If this is indeed a place where optimizations are needed, then what you really should optimize is the following two things:

- buffer allocation
- number of calls to `read()` and `write()`

For small buffers of 100 to 1000 bytes, there's no reason to use `malloc()` and the like, just allocate the buffer on the stack, it's going to be the fastest. Unless, of course, you want to return pointers to these buffers from the function, in which case you probably should use `malloc()`. Otherwise, you should consider using global/static arrays instead of dynamically allocated ones.

As for the I/O calls, call `read()` and `write()` with the entire buffer size. Don't call them to read or write single bytes. Transitions to the kernel and back do have cost.

Further, if you expect to need to work with fairly large files in RAM, consider using file mapping.

Answer (score 4):

`stat` et al. allow you to get the file size. http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat

Or, if you can't use that, `lseek` http://linux.die.net/man/2/lseek (pay particular attention to the return value)

If you can't use that either, you can always `realloc` your buffer as you go.

I'm leaving it up to you to implement it since this is obviously an assignment. ;)

Comment: And if you `realloc()`, you can do that in a logarithmic way, instead of extending the buffer one byte at a time.

Comment: what if sometimes I need to read it from STDIN from terminal(fd=0)?

Comment: @AlexZern then you have little choice, you'll have to `realloc` as you go: since stdin is a stream you can't get its size nor seek back.

Answer (score 2):

Before optimizing anything you have to **profile your code**. Many tools are available to do that:

- valgrind
- Intel VTune
- AQTime
- AMD CodeAnalyst

Answer (score 1):

define an array that automatically straightforward extensions.
like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct dynarray {
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
    char *array;
} DynArray;

DynArray *da_make(size_t init_size){
    DynArray *da;
    if(NULL==(da=(DynArray*)malloc(sizeof(DynArray)))){
        perror("memory not enough");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if(NULL==(da->array=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*init_size))){
        perror("memory not enough");
        exit(-1);
    }
    da->size = 0;
    da->capacity=init_size;
    return da;
}

void da_add(DynArray *da, char value){
    da->array[da->size] = value;
    if(++da->size == da->capacity){
        da->array=(char*)realloc(da->array, sizeof(char)*(da->capacity += 1024));
        if(NULL==da){
            perror("memory not enough");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
}

void da_free(DynArray *da){
    free(da->array);
    free(da);
}

int main(void) {
    DynArray *da;
    char charbuf;
    int i;

    da = da_make(128);
    while(read(0, &charbuf, 1)!=0)
        da_add(da, charbuf);
    for(i=0;i<da->size;++i)
        putchar(da->array[i]);
    da_free(da);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need everything in memory?  You can have chunks of reads, process, read next chunk etc.,
Unless you have enough memory, you cannot keep all in your buff. What is your goal?

Answer (score 0):

If, as you say, you're only using *system calls*, you may be able to get away with using the entire heap as a buffer.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

size_t sz;
void fix(x){signal(SIGSEGV,fix);sbrk(sz *= 2);}
int main() {
    sz = getpagesize();
    signal(SIGSEGV,fix);
    char *buf = sbrk(sz);
    int fd = open("filename", O_RDWR);
    read(fd, buf, -1);
}
```

But if you happen to call a library function which uses malloc, Kablooey!

The `brk` and `sbrk` functions give you direct access to the same heap that malloc uses. But without any of malloc's "overhead". And without any of malloc's *features*, like `free`, `realloc`. `sbrk` is called with a size in bytes and returns a `void *`. `brk` is called with a pointer value (ie. you just *imagine* the pointer into existence and *declare* it to `brk`, in a way), and returns a `void *`.

By using `brk` or `sbrk` to allocate memory, it uses the same space that malloc will try to setup and use on the first call to `malloc` or `realloc`. And many library functions use malloc *under the hood*, so there are many ways for this code to break. It's a very bizarre and interesting area.

The signal handler here is also very dangerous. It gives you automatic unlimited space, but of course, if you run into any other kind of segmentation violation, like dereferencing a NULL-pointer, the handler cannot fix that, and it can no longer crash. So this can send the program into a nasty loop: retrying the memory access, allocating more space, retrying the memory access, allocating more space.

Comment: Can you give explanation about what you wrote,please?

Comment: Edited with some explanation.

Comment: I think this is dangerous if you do not really know what you are doung. If you use `malloc’ related functios (even `new`) any time it will mess the heap.

Comment: Thanks! `void fix(x){signal(SIGSEGV,fix);sbrk(sz *= 2);}` compiler says error.